# How do I show that $P(|X-Y|>1/n)=0 \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ then $X=Y$ a.s

Tags: probability-theory

How do I show that if  $P(|X-Y|>1/n)=0 \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ then $X=Y$ a.s
Though this looks fairly obvious but how do i put it down rigorously . Can I say that $P(|X-Y|>0)=P\big(\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\{|X-Y|>1/n\} \big) \leq P(|X-Y|>1/2)=0$ which implies that $P(X=Y)=1$ i.e. $X=Y$ a.s

Is the reasoning correct?

Comment: What if X=Y+1/10? then P[X=Y] =0, but P[|X-Y|>1/2]=0

Comment: @PeterR Why does $X-Y=10 \implies P[X=Y]=0$ ?

Comment: You confused intersection and union. Being positive means being greater than some $\frac{1}{n}$. So you have to put a union there. The result follows then from the continuity of a measure.

Comment: @MooS That was very stupid of me. Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that

$$\mathbb{P} \left(\left[\vert X - Y \vert > \frac{1}{n}\right]\right) = 0 $$

Then 
$$[X \neq Y] \subset \cup_{n} \left[\vert X - Y \vert > \frac{1}{n}\right] $$

Therefore 
$$\mathbb{P} \left( [X \neq Y ]\right) \leq \mathbb{P} \left(\cup_{n} \left[\vert X - Y \vert > \frac{1}{n}\right]\right)\leq \sum_n\mathbb{P} \left( \left[\vert X - Y \vert > \frac{1}{n}\right]\right) = 0 $$

We conclude that $\mathbb{P} \left( [X = Y ]\right) = 1$ that is $X = Y$ a.s.

**remark:** we denote $[X = Y]$ the event $\{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega)  =Y (\omega)\}$ and  we consider $X, Y$ random variables on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{B}, \mathbb{P})$

Comment: Thanks your answer was nice and clear.